# Assets in .scss not compiling with HTTPS like rest of app assets

Tags: ssl, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, asset-pipeline, sprockets

My Rails 4 app has an issue with some assets pre-compiling with HTTP instead of HTTPS. All CSS and JS are being complied to paths with HTTPS and images in views are also using HTTPS. This issue is that in the css.scss file, I have:

```
background: image-url('bg.jpg') no-repeat;
```

When compiled this uses HTTP not HTTPS like the rest of assets.

I have set config to use SSL in production:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "https://www.example.com"
config.force_ssl = true
```

And pre-compiled the assets in production environment, but not working. I have tried using `asset_url` instead of `image-url` but that doesn't work either.

I am using Rails (4.0.8), Sass-rails (4.0.2), Sprockets (2.11.0) and Sprockets-rails (2.0.1).

Why aren't the assets from css.scss compiling with HTTPS?

Comment: I am running into a similar situation with similar setup.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was caused by some assets still lingering in `./tmp/cache` in my production environment. When I removed these, the recent configuration changes in `./config/environments/production.rb` were picked up correctly. If that fails, I'd also recommend doing `rm -rf public/assets` and `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` to ensure that you are seeing the correct assets and things are not getting cached. Hope this helps.

(edit: see also - https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/124)